# material-ui select dropdown looking like a chip

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to create a similar Dropdown `Select` with `material-ui` that looks like a `Chip` component like this?

[image]

If so could you direct me where to start?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible, Material UI have variant type of select, you can see and try those in the following link :

**[more and advanced select component in Material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/)**

Comment: Does not look like variant has at all similar type of select. Are you talking about overrides section?